# How do I serialize chrono::DateTime fields as ISODate when using the Rust Mongo driver prototype?

Tags: mongodb, rust, bson, serde

Datetime fields in structs are being serialized to `String`s instead of `ISODate`s when using the [Rust Mongo driver prototype](https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mongo-rust-driver-prototype). How do I get the fields to be saved as `ISODate`?

```rust
use chrono::{DateTime, Utc};
use mongodb::oid::ObjectId;
use mongodb::{
    coll::Collection, db::Database, db::ThreadedDatabase, error::Error, Client, ThreadedClient,
};
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Clone, Debug)]
struct Person {
    pub _id: ObjectId,
    pub date: DateTime<Utc>,
}

fn main() {
    let client = Client.with_uri("mongodb://localhost:27017").unwrap();
    let p = Person {
        _id: ObjectId::new().unwrap(),
        date: Utc::now(),
    };
    let document = mongodb::to_bson(p).unwrap().as_document();
    if document.is_some() {
        client
            .db("my_db")
            .collection("mycollection")
            .insert_one(document, None)
            .unwrap();
    }
}
```

On querying the DB, the record contains a date string (in ISO format); I expected it to be an `ISODate`.

Comment: try to use [`UtcDateTime`](https://docs.rs/mongodb/0.3.12/mongodb/struct.UtcDateTime.html)

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that `UtcDatetime` would work. However, just like for `i32`, `i64`, or `String`, I don't have to use `bson::Bson::String` or `bson::Bson::I32` or `bson::Bson::I64` in my structs, the serializer should take care of the conversion transparently. Adding variants over struct fields would also be an acceptable solution.

Comment: That not possible `mongodb` can't implement `Serialize` for `DateTime`, their need a wrapper, and it's look like `bson` have it and share it. Why not use it ?

Comment: The official driver has the same issue. If I put a serialized struct it writes a string, but when I update it using doc with `Utc` it writes data that can't be deserialized 

Answer (score 5):

With mongodb and bson crates in version 2.0.0-beta.1

In Cargo.toml, add the feature chrono-0_4:

```
bson = { version = "2.0.0-beta.1", features = ["chrono-0_4"] }
```

Then annotate your field with

```
use chrono::{DateTime, Utc};

#[serde(with = "bson::serde_helpers::chrono_datetime_as_bson_datetime")]
date: DateTime<Utc>,
```

Comment: How do you handle this when the date is Option<DateTime<Utc>>?

Comment: @ClarkMcCauley I made my own wrapper https://gist.github.com/ImTheSquid/b5f34c39c5c4a7760b3917c394b9ec07

Answer (score 4):

You can choose deserialization as ISO string with serde_helpers.

https://docs.rs/bson/1.2.2/bson/serde_helpers/index.html

```rust
use mongodb::bson::DateTime;
use mongodb::bson::serde_helpers::bson_datetime_as_iso_string;

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Clone, Debug)]
struct Person {
    pub _id: ObjectId,
    #[serde(with = "bson_datetime_as_iso_string")]
    date: DateTime,
}
```