# How to workaround async incompatibilities when using mongodb-1.2.2 and rocket-0.5.0-rc.1?

Tags: mongodb, rust, rust-tokio, rust-rocket

I am working on building a [rocket](https://crates.io/crates/rocket) REST API using a [mongodb](https://crates.io/crates/mongodb) database. I have been able to successfully create a connection and start up the server without errors:

```toml
# Cargo.toml
[dependencies]
rocket = "0.5.0-rc.1"
dotenv = "0.15.0"
mongodb = "1.2.2"

[dependencies.openssl]
version = "0.10"
features = ["vendored"]
```

```
#[get("/")]
pub async fn index(client: &State<ClientPointer>) -> &'static str {
    let _dbs = client.0.list_databases(None, None).await.unwrap();

    "Fetched databases"
}

#[launch]
async fn rocket() -> _ {
    let client = database::connect::pool(1, 32).await.unwrap();

    rocket::build()
        .mount("/", routes!(routes::index))
        .manage(database::rocket::ClientPointer(client))
}
```

However, when the route is invoked I get the following output:

```
>> Matched: (index) GET /
thread 'rocket-worker-thread' panicked at 'there is no timer running, must be called from the context of a Tokio 0.2.x runtime', C:\Users\lukasdiegelmann\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\tokio-0.2.25\src\time\driver\handle.rs:24:32
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
   >> Handler index panicked.
   >> This is an application bug.
   >> A panic in Rust must be treated as an exceptional event.
   >> Panicking is not a suitable error handling mechanism.
   >> Unwinding, the result of a panic, is an expensive operation.
   >> Panics will severely degrade application performance.
   >> Instead of panicking, return `Option` and/or `Result`.
   >> Values of either type can be returned directly from handlers.
   >> A panic is treated as an internal server error.
   >> Outcome: Failure
   >> No 500 catcher registered. Using Rocket default.
   >> Response succeeded.
```

So it seems like there is something wrong with the versioning of the used async runtime. But I could not find where, because the error do not really give me a hint and the mongodb rust driver appears to be using a `0.2.x` version of tokio namely version `~0.2.18`.

**Edit:** I have gained a little bit more insight and it seems like `rocket-0.5.0-rc.1` has started using a `tokio-1.x` runtime, whereas `mongodb-1.2.2` has not. This obviously imposes a big problem, since I will either have to have two runtimes run simultaneously or have to ditch mongodb for now, which is not exactly the definition of a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB has [released a `2.0.0-beta` version](https://crates.io/crates/mongodb/2.0.0-beta.1) of its driver that uses `tokio-1.x`.

Comment: You might need to use this answer for your date serialization too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67890760/3970387